# Google Play Games statistics not updating in Developer Console

Tags: android, statistics, google-play

I have a problem in the Google Play Developer Console with the Games Services.

I added all the required stuff to my Android game to synchronize and login using Google Games Services, I added some achievements that are working well, i can see and unlock them from my app, etc.

So my question is, if I published the game with the changes last friday (3 days ago), why the developer console achievements statistics are not getting updated? I understand that it can take some time, but more than two days?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Ok, now the stats are getting updated, more than three days needed to update them. It would be great to see it in the docs

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the exact same situation.
I launched achievements 3 days ago, and the achievements stats are also not available.
It may be a problem on Google's side.